# Not showing x-axis label in lower configuration

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts graphs, Start point of highcharts is showing in my laptop (maximum resolution: 1920*1080).

But when I am an open same graph in a lower system: maximum resolution (1368*768) [That time the first point of x-axis not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqz3Q.png)

**Note :** Given image is not match with data but graph is same.

**CODE :**

```
$('#call_cc_graph_data').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline',
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'CPS vs Time'
                    },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    min : 1533873600000,
                    max : 1533945599000,
                },
                series:[{
                        name: 'CC',
                        data: [[1533876120000,1],[1533876240000,1],[1533876840000,2],[1533876900000,1],[1533877200000,7],[1533877260000,4],[1533877320000,1]]
                }]
                });
```

Expected result of image : It needs to show value 05:00 on starting point of x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `xAxis.startOnTick` [Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.startOnTick) and maybe `xAxis.tickInterval` [Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval)

```
xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      min : 1533873600000,
      max : 1533945599000,
      startOnTick:true,
      tickInterval:3600 * 1000 // If 2 hours step is too large 
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/d9xqh1e4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change default xAxis units option:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    units: [
        [
            'second', [20, 40]
        ],
        [
            'minute', [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30]
        ],
        [
            'hour', [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 12]
        ],
        [
            'day', [1, 2]
        ],
        [
            'week', [1, 2]
        ],
        [
            'month', [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
        ],
        [
            'year',
            null
        ]
    ],
    min: 1533876120000,
    max: 1533945599000
},
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pskqo6ad/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.units

Similar problem: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5437